# Screen Frozen despite RPI working

Tags: raspbian, display, screen

I have set up my Raspberry Pi to display the contents of an Ice weasel tab permanently. However, the screen has now frozen and I can't seem to recover it. The raspberry pi is still on and functioning well (i can vnc and ssh into it), apart from the lack of display. This is the second time this has occurred in two weeks. Last time a simple restart fixed the issue but I am looking for a more permanent solution.

Comment: If you can SSH into the RPi, have you checked if there is a difference in the processes running before and during a freeze?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After probing the test points on the raspberry pi I discovered that the voltage was low (sometimes as low as 4.3v instead of the intended 5v). I proceeded to buy another power supply with a greater voltage (5.25v). This did not solve anything.

As the voltage difference was usually about 0.7v different from the desired my first thought was that a diode had blown and I went to the schematic and probed all the diodes till I found one that had blown. It controls the HDMI output (hence the screen freeze). I presume that this was the problem but because I am hopeless at soldering a smd I just bought a new board.